# .htaccess RewriteRule, it gives my page without css

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to put change my url www.mywebsite.com/team.php 
to www.mywebsite.com/team/ using .htaccess.

I tried this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^equipe/?$    equipe.php     [NC,L]
```

What happens is that I can now have access to both www.mywebsite.com/team.php and www.mywebsite.com/team/ but when I go to www.mywebsite.com/team/ there is no css at all.
Is it about a server configuration issue or code issue? thanks!

Comment: all css links must be relative to the root, ie with forward slash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+rewriting+missing+css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your css linking

if you have your css defined with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

when accessed through www.mywebsite.com/team.php it may be looking for your css file at `www.mywebsite.com/style.css`

when accessed through www.mywebsite.com/team/ it may be looking for your css file at `www.mywebsite.com/team/style.css` returning a 404 instead.

If this is your issue use a `/` in your css href to always declare your css file at the root of the web server so that all all web pages with that code snippet will load correctly no matter how deep in folders they are (or appear to be).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mystyle.css">
```

Comment: Wow! I'd never expected this! Thanks a lot, everythings works fine so far :)